# Throw an exception during runtime using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, testing, runtime

I'm working on an batch application right now that utilizes a class to email out any errors caught during runtime so that the support team will know the batch failed immediately. Basically, the entire batch process is kicked off using a `run` method in my launcher class. The run method has a try/catch block that will send the email if any exceptions make it back to the launcher class without being handled.

Is there a  way to test my email functionality utilizing Eclipse's debugging tools? I would like to kick off the application then have a way to just throw an uncaught exception so I can see the email show up in my inbox.

I don't want to put a `throw` statement in my code, because I really don't want to make the method  use the "`throws`" tag. I am hoping that I can use the debugger to pause the app and then somehow just tell Eclipse to throw the app an exception.

Is this possible?

Comment: Throw an unchecked exception, such as `RuntimeException` or any of its subclasses, or just do `Object x = null; x.toString();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add a `throws` declaration for an unchecked exception, by definition.

Just add:

```
throw new RuntimeException("testing");
```

to throw a [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

Comment: I tried to `throw RuntimeException();` I feel like a complete idiot for forgetting to add the `new` keyword. Thanks